# Кросскомпиляция на mingw32: не выполняются вызовы printf

Tags: winapi, кросс-компиляция, c++, linux

Компилятор mingw32 (платформа Linux, целевая - Windows), линковка, проблема

Проблема в том, что при запуске в Windows не вып-ся printf (windows.h включается в проект нормально), gdb не выводит ошибок, пути верные (проверял). Подскажите, что не так?

**Make-file**:

```
MainCpp=main

GppCompilerWin32="///usr/bin/i586-pc-mingw32-g++"

RemoveDebugInfoGppCompilerWin32="///usr/bin/i586-pc-mingw32-strip"

LibWin=-I"///usr/i586-pc-mingw32/sys-root/mingw/include" -L"///usr/i586-pc-mingw32/sys-root/mingw/lib" -lmingw32 -luser32 -lgdi32 -lwinmm

GppCompilerWin32Flags=-mwindows

win32:

    $(GppCompilerWin32) $(GppCompilerWin32Flags) -o $(MainCpp)win32.exe $(MainCpp).cpp 
    $(LibWin) $(RemoveDebugInfoGppCompilerWin32) $(MainCpp)win32.exe
```

Comment: проблема с линковкой или запуском? уж определитесь.

Comment: А hello world работает?

Comment: и размер файла не меняется при изменении писка подкл библиотек и запуск не выводит printf. сама программа
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
 printf("HELLO\n");
 system("pause");
 return 0;
}

Comment: может просто makefile проверяет, что бинарник уже есть, не пересобирает его по новой? удалите бинарник и пересоберите.

Comment: нет, дата изменения файла меняется, но все же я попробовал что вы сказали - не помогло

Comment: Хм, а сообщения при компиляции хоть какие-нибудь выдаются? Вы пишете про gdb -- а им можно оттрассировать вызов `printf`? (Или лучше `puts`, она проще.)

Comment: м, может все выполняется, просто консоль быстро закрывается. А может бинарник собирается не для той платформы. В линуксе есть такая утилита `file` - она позволяет подсмотреть тип файла. Запустите в консоли `file your_bin` и покажите вывод.

Comment: [nebrit63@linux Compile to Win(Console App) with MAKE-FILE]$ file main_win32.exe
main_win32.exe: PE32 executable for MS Windows (GUI) Intel 80386 32-bit

Comment: gdb .exe файлы похоже не поддерживает - "не могу открыть бинарный файл"(понятное дело он не должен их поддерживать, я просто попробовал открыть на дебаг), а пакета mingw32 для дебага похоже нет(нашел в синаптике только к программам с GTK)

Comment: Вот вывод дебага linux-приложения. То есть dbg-ер работает, но не с .exe виндовскими:
[nebrit63@linux ~]$ g++ -o 1 1.o
[nebrit63@linux ~]$ gdb
GNU gdb (GDB) 7.2-alt2 (ALT Linux)
(gdb) file 1
Reading symbols from /home/nebrit63/1...done.
(gdb) start
Temporary breakpoint 1 at 0x80483e7
Starting program: /home/nebrit63/1 

Temporary breakpoint 1, 0x080483e7 in main ()
(gdb) start
The program being debugged has been started already.
Start it from the beginning? (y or n)

Comment: так раз у Вас бинарник для windows, то и запускать его нужно под windows, а не linux. Либо установите wine.

Comment: А что происходит при запуске в настоящей винде из командной строки?

Answer (score 1):

> Проблема в том, что при запуске в Windows не вып-ся printf (windows.h включается в проект нормально)

windows.h никакого отношения к printf не имеет! printf это библиотечная функция clib. Чекайте свой компайлер и систему сборки.

Если интерес не пропал - поднимайте тему, у меня есть решения.